# How to find the corresponding class in clf.predict_proba()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a number of classes and corresponding feature vectors, and when I run predict_proba() I will get this:

```
classes = ['one','two','three','one','three']

feature = [[0,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1]]

from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB

clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(feature,classes)
clf.predict_proba([0,1,1,0])
>> array([[ 0.48247836,  0.40709111,  0.11043053]])
```

I would like to get what probability that corresponds to what class. On this page it says that they are ordered by arithmetical order, i'm not 100% sure of what that means: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba

Does it mean that I have go trough my training examples assign the corresponding index to the first encounter of a class, or is there a command like

`clf.getClasses() = ['one','two','three']?`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Just use the `.classes_` attribute of the classifier to recover the mapping. In your example that gives:

```
>>> clf.classes_
array(['one', 'three', 'two'], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

And thanks for putting a minimalistic reproduction script in your question, it makes answering really easy by just copy and pasting in a IPython shell :)

Comment: For a single sample, `zip(clf.classes_, clf.predict_proba(x)[0])` gives readable output.

Comment: is there a way to pass the predefined order to the classifier?

Comment: You can name your classes `0, 1, 2...` directly if you wish. Otherwise you habe to use the `clf.classes_` attribute to do the reverse mapping.

Answer (score 22):

```
import pandas as pd
test = [[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0]]
pd.DataFrame(clf.predict_proba(test), columns=clf.classes_)

Out[2]:
         one       three         two
0   0.542815    0.361876    0.095309
1   0.306431    0.612863    0.080706
```

Answer (score 15):

As a rule, any attribute in a learner that ends with _ is a learned one. In your case you're looking for `clf.classes_`.

Generally in Python, you can use the `dir` function to find out which attributes an object has.