# Python predict_proba class identification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Suppose my labeled data has two classes 1 and 0. When I run predict_proba on the test set it returns an array with two columns. Which column corresponds to which class ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858652/how-to-find-the-corresponding-class-in-clf-predict-proba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column 0 corresponds to the class 0, column 1 corresponds to the class 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that by printing the classes with `print(estimator.classes_)`. The array will have the same order like the output.